# registerForActivityResult IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity

I have an exception in my "ActivityResultRegistry". I begin on java, so I'm not an expert :s

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Traitement du résultat de l'activité réservation
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> reservationLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if(result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Réservation confirmée", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    );

    Toast.makeText(this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.MenuRechercher:
            Log.i("LocDVD", "Rechercher un film");
            return true;

        case R.id.MenuReserver:
            // Log.i("LocDVD", "Réserver un film");
            // Lance l'activité qui affiche la fenêtre de réservation
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Reservation.class);
            reservationLauncher.launch(intent);
            return true;

        case R.id.MenuMagasin:
            Log.i("LocDVD", "Acheter un film");
            return true;

        case R.id.MenuContact:
            Log.i("LocDVD", "Nous contacter");
            return true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The logcat return me this :
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.event_manager_mobil, PID: 11654
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner com.example.event_manager_mobil.MainActivity@9cff8570 is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. I put this function in onCreate